# error: module not found: org.lwjgl.natives in multi-module gradle build

Tags: gradle, lwjgl, java-module, java-12

I'm getting the following errors trying to run a multi-module gradle build:

```
/Users/ashley/Personal/juggernaut/display/src/main/java/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: org.lwjgl.natives
  requires org.lwjgl.natives;
                    ^
/Users/ashley/Personal/juggernaut/display/src/main/java/module-info.java:3: error: module not found: org.lwjgl.glfw.natives
  requires org.lwjgl.glfw.natives;
                         ^
/Users/ashley/Personal/juggernaut/display/src/main/java/module-info.java:4: error: module not found: org.lwjgl.opengl.natives
  requires org.lwjgl.opengl.natives;
                           ^
/Users/ashley/Personal/juggernaut/display/src/main/java/module-info.java:5: error: module not found: org.lwjgl.stb.natives
  requires org.lwjgl.stb.natives;
                        ^
/Users/ashley/Personal/juggernaut/display/src/main/java/module-info.java:6: error: module not found: org.lwjgl.assimp.natives
  requires org.lwjgl.assimp.natives;
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
├── build.gradle
├── display
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   ├── module-info.java
├── engine
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   ├── module-info.java
└── settings.gradle
```

the `module-info.java` for `display` requires the necessary LWJGL3 modules:

```
module uk.ashleybye.juggernaut.display {
  requires org.lwjgl.natives;
  requires org.lwjgl.glfw.natives;
  requires org.lwjgl.opengl.natives;
  requires org.lwjgl.stb.natives;
  requires org.lwjgl.assimp.natives;
  exports uk.ashleybye.juggernaut.display;
}
```

The relevant dependencies are included in the `build.gradle`:

```
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.2.2"
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-macos"

dependencies {
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:$lwjglVersion"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp:$lwjglVersion"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:$lwjglVersion"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:$lwjglVersion"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:$lwjglVersion"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:$lwjglVersion"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
}
```

Engine `requires uk.ashleybye.juggernaut.display;` and has an implementation dependency: `implementation project(":display")`.

My version info:

```
./gradlew --version                                          Sat 17 Aug 09:31:44 2019

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-07-10 20:38:12 UTC
Revision:     3245f748c7061472da4dc184991919810f7935a5

Kotlin:       1.3.31
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          12 (Oracle Corporation 12+33)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

Why can gradle not find the modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `module-info.class` doesn't need to include any natives at all.

Remove all the `.natives`s from each `requires`.

Also, you can compact your `build.gradle`:

```
["", "-assimp", "-glfw", "-openal", "-opengl", "-stb"].each {
    String base = "org.lwjgl:lwjgl$it:$lwjgl_version"
    implementation base
    runtimeOnly = "$base:natives-$lwjgl_natives"
}
```

You may refer to [this project](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/imgui-gl/build.gradle) of ours for reference, it's a multi-module project, which relies heavily on lwjgl and uses JPMS too.